# How to detect if a function is annotated with @property

Tags: d, phobos

Is it possible using D's builtin traits and/or std.traits to detect whether a function (either within a class/struct or without) is annotated with @property? I know @property isn't *really* an attribute, but I thought `__traits(getAttributes, ...)` might do it (no such luck).

Comment: Why do you need it? When in doubt - use parenthesis!

Comment: You can even call functions without `@property` without parenthesis, so I don't see an actual need for that.

Comment: I'm attempting to write a template function that generates a "builder" class for an arbitrary class. In my project I have been using @property strictly as setters/getters, so the idea is to get all of the functions from a class annotated with the property attribute, and then generate the builder methods.

Comment: Doesn't std.traits.functionAttributes work in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I would think that it would be better to just test that the expression you want to use compiles (e.g. `is(typeof(var.prop))`), but if for some reason you really need to know that a function is marked with `@property`, then you can use [std.traits.functionAttributes](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#functionAttributes) to get that information. Something like

```
enum isProperty = (functionAttributes!(MyType.prop) & FunctionAttribute.property) != 0;
```

should work.